# Loop to execute an order to multiple files

Tags: linux

I have a series of files:

```
AHB_A1.fastq
AHB_A2.fastq
AHB_A3.fastq
```

I would like to run this command in all of them as a loop

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless 1 = $.' AHB_A1.fastq > AHB_A1.fq
```

I am trying different commands to run them as a loop but I am getting different errors. Could you help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67933282/loop-to-execute-a-perl-command-in-multiple-files ?

Comment: yes it is, maybe its more clear this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the files. In bash, you can use parameter expansion to remove the extension from the file name:

```sh
for fastq in *.fastq ; do
    perl -pe 'chomp unless 1 == $.' "$fastq" > "${fastq%.fastq}.fq
done
```

Or, you can tell Perl to edit the files "in place" leaving a backup, then you don't need any loop at all:

```
perl -i~ -pe 'chomp unless 1 == $. || eof; $. = 0 if eof' *.fastq
```

- `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the numeric equality operator. You can't assign to 1, but you can compare to it (that's why I usually write `1 == $.` and not `$. == 1`, so Perl can catch when I use `=` instead of `==`.
- `-i~` changes the files in place, leaving the backups with the tilde appended to their names
- [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof) doesn't reset `$.`, you need to do it yourself at the end of each file.